# Error SDK Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am using google translator I do not speak English, I hope you understand.

I've got a problem with the facebook api. I'm all right facendo only an error message appears from the api that I can not solve.

If someone can help me I appreciate it.

Embrace.

Look at the error message that appears:

```
(!) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Facebook needs the PHP CURL extension.' in C: \ wamp \ www \ base_facebook.php on line 19
(!) Exception: Facebook needs the PHP CURL extension. in C: \ wamp \ www \ base_facebook.php on line 19
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0026 367088 {main} () .. \ convite.php: 0
2 0.0043 390976 require_once ('C: \ wamp \ www \ facebook.php') .. \ convite.php: 7
3 0.0100 644736 require_once ('C: \ wamp \ www \ base_facebook.php') .. \ facebook.php: 18
```

My code to invite friends, I got a tutorial on the net

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
 <head>
    Facebook Invite Friends <title> PHP Example </ title>
 </ head>
 <body>
     <php
         require_once 'facebook.php';
         require_once 'base_facebook.php';
         UseGraphAPI ();

         invite1 InviteFriends $ = new ();
         $ invite1-> SetMainTitle ("Photo Mania");
         $ invite1-> setContent ("Invite all your friends");
         $ invite1-> Render ();
     ?>
 </ body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Enable CURL on your server.